# Custom Filter for angularjs pagination

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pagination

I am trying to apply a condition to the pagination using angularjs.

The condition is returned from a function GetParameterVisibility(x).

This is what I have:

```
dir-paginate="x in itemsToDisplay | orderBy:'Name' | filter:textFilter | itemsPerPage: pageSize"
```

What I would like to do is filter based on the bool returned from the function, but also be able to apply the text filter on the items shown.

How do I apply this additional condition which will also work with the text filter.

e.g.

```
dir-paginate="x in itemsToDisplay | orderBy:'Name' | filter:(textFilter || GetParameterVisibility(x)) | itemsPerPage: pageSize"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create filter which does processing of your function, in your application module:

```
.filter('fvisible', ['myService',function(myService) {
  return function(input) {
    return myService.GetParameterVisibility(input);//or any logic with this
  };
}]);
```

Then you chain filters, because the order is important, and data from one filter filtered goes to another filter.

```
| filter:textFilter | filter:fvisible |
```

With filter chaining you can have **or** statement with filters. I am not pretty sure what you want to return basing on bool, but this is how you can create your own filter processing it. 
Also you have to inject getVisibility function, so you can do this creating service with this function inside and inject to filter fvisible.

```
.service('myService',function(){
 this.GetParameterVisibility = function(){
      //
 };
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for your post! I have added the filter and service to my angularjs controller. I get a syntax error from the "." at the start of filter and service. where do I add this to my code?

Comment: angular.module('formularzeApp')
  .filter('x',function(){...}).service('y',function(){}); you add it after return of module method through chaining.

Comment: Cyan, getting closer but still not working. I have posted what I have above. Would really appreciate a bit more help!

Comment: made an edit to your post. I am not sure what should be returned from bool filter, if 0 or 1 or rather array of filtered elements.

Answer (score 0):

Cyan, thanks for your help I think I am nearly there. (In my defence I normally write c# code)

I now have this:

```
<div class="DataItem" dir-paginate="x in itemsToDisplay | orderBy:'Name' | filter:textFilter | filter:fvisible | itemsPerPage: pageSize" current-page="currentPage">



   var app = angular.module('parametersApp', ['angularUtils.directives.dirPagination']);
        app.controller('parametersController', function ($scope, $http) {   //Code    });


 angular.module('parametersApp').filter('fvisible', ['myService', function (myService) {
            return function (input) {
                return myService.GetParameterVisibility(input);
            };
        }]).service('myService', function () {
            this.GetParameterVisibility = function (parameter) {

                if ($('#chkInAlert').is(':checked')) {
                    if (parameter.AlertPriority > 0) {
                        return true;
                    }
                    else {
                        return false;
                    }

                }
                else {
                    return true;
                }

            };
        });
```

Doesn't cause any errors which is a bonus, but it doesn't seem to work either.

One question is how does it pass in the object x to the GetParameterVisibility function from my dir-paginate="x in itemsToDisplay..

Comment: Change angular.module('parametersApp').filter to app.filter and ('parametersController', function ($scope, $http) {   //Code    }); to ('parametersController', ['$scope','$http',function ($scope, $http) {   //Code    }]);

Comment: Thanks for your help Cyan. I have given up and now apply the filtering before assigning the array of objects to display.

Comment: How do you determine visibility? Is it true/false for specified value in object or always true or false?